# C++ bitwise operations, max value of 12 bit int

Tags: c++, bit

So the max value of a 12 bit int should be 4095.

```
char a, b, c;
int i = (a>>4)<<8 | (b>>4)<<8 | (c>>4);
```

So the max value that i should be able to be is 4095; however, the value of i often is the max value of a 32 bit integer. How do I make the max value of i be 4095???

Comment: You could reduce the maximum value by using `uint16_t` instead of a signed integer.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Do you mean `(b>>4)<<4` in your code? I can't see how it makes sense otherwise.  Do you know about sign extension? Is your `char` type signed?

Comment: I agree with Carl that the `(b>>4)<<8` is almost certainly a typo.  The `>>4` is curious, too. It seems that you will get the top 4 bits of the value in `a`, and the top 4 bits of the value in `b`, and the top 4 bits of the value in `c`. If your plain `char` is signed and your compiler does arithmetic shift right and you have any bytes in the range 0x80..0xFF, then you will have too many one bits around and your values will be screwed up because of that. Fundamentally, you've not shown enough information: how are the variables initialized; what are the sample values; what output do you expect.

Comment: `char` might be signed, so sign extension might be confusing matters. Use unsigned types, or extreme care, when wrangling bits.

Answer (score 0):

With a typo, it looks like you want the top 4 bits of each character.  Use `unsigned char` to prevent sign-extension:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0xFB;
    unsigned char b = 0xFC;
    unsigned char c = 0xFE;
    int i = (a>>4)<<8 | (b>>4)<<4 | (c>>4);
    printf("%x %d\n",i,i);
}
```

Output:

```
fff 4095
```

Comment: But 2^12 = 4096 then why the output is 4095?

Comment: @ViruMax 12 bits can hold 4096 *values*...from 0 to 4095 (0x000-0xFFF)